# Errororg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

I created an app which requires a log in system. I created the registration, it works, but when I want to login I got this error message

Errororg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

I gave Internet Permission!

My login Class is

```
package com.quizonwheels.quizfinal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
 private Button openMore;
 private TextView openRegister;
 private Button btn_login;
    private EditText email,password;
    private static String URL_LOGIN = "https://test-onaca.lapausenii.ro/login.php";
    private ProgressBar loading;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        openMore = findViewById(R.id.learnmore);
        openRegister = findViewById(R.id.openRegister);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading1);
        email = findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        openRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Register.class));
            }
        });

        openMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://quizonwheels.com")));
            }
        });

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty())
                {
                    login(mEmail,mPass);

                }
                else {
                    email.setError("Please insert E-mail");
                    password.setError("Please insert Password");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void login( final String email, final String password) {
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String succes = jsonObject.getString("succes");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");
                    if(succes.equals("1"))
                    {
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = object.getString("name").trim();
                            String email = object.getString("email").trim();
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Succes \nYour name:" +name+"\n Your Email:" +email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error" +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error!" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

And my php code is:

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== 'POST')
  {
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      require_once 'connect.php';

      $sql = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
      $response = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $result = array();
      $result['login']= array();
      if(mysqli_num_rows($respone)===1) {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);
          if(password_verify($password, $row['password']))
          {
              $index['name']=$row['name'];
              $index['email']= $row['email'];

              array_push($result['login'],$index);
              $result['succes'] = "1";
              $result['message']="succes";
              echo json_encode($result);

              mysqli_close($conn);

          }
          else {
              $result['succes']="0";
              $result['message']="error";
              echo json_encode($result);

              mysqli_close($conn);

          }
      }
  }
?>
```

I was looking on google to find the solution but I couldnt find one.

Comment: Apparently, `response` is not a valid JSON string. If you log it in your exception handling, does it contain anything that isn't JSON? Does it contain anything at all?

Comment: What should I edit?

Comment: Either run your app in debug mode and set a breakpoint in your `catch (JSONException e)` block so you can see what the value of `response` is, or log `response` in that same block. The first step in debugging a JSON error is checking what the source string is.

Comment: I go it, I will try it now, thank you!

Comment: It's a null ...

Comment: I would recommend you to hardcode email and password in your php code ($email = 'myemail@email.com') and run the URL in chrome. Look at the response then to ensure that PHP is producing the response as you would expect to see it.

Comment: It shows me nothing

Comment: So PHP is not outputting anything. Next step should then be to add an `else` to every single `if`, so you can see which one is failing. Then you'll find you have a typo in `mysqli_num_rows($respone)`: `$respone` instead of `$response`.

Answer (score 0):

My rep doesn't allow me to comment, so hopefully I'm allowed to share my thoughts like this. Your code only outputs some JSON if a given email address was found in the database.

Are you sure you're feeding it an existing email address, with no duplicates? Also, consider offloading the hash verification to the RDBMS. This might speed up the script, and it result in a clearer separation of concerns. You'll also want to escape the user input you're feeding into the SQL, as mysqli_query doesn't do any escaping by default. A better approach might be to use PDO prepared statements.